# foreach loop with conditions on a List object's attribute

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a foreach loop that needs to iterate only if the 'Valid' property is set to true. Unfortunately if 'Valid' is set to false for the first item in the list it exits the entire loop.

Does anyone know the best method for using a condition in a foreach loop? Below is what I have right now.

```
foreach (var course in agentNewTraining.AllCoursesTaken.TakeWhile(c => c.Valid))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Where` method.

```
foreach (var course in agentNewTraining.AllCoursesTaken.Where(c => c.Valid))
```

What your code does now is take elements until one which doesn't match the condition is found. In case the first element of your list, for example, doesn't match the predicate, you would get an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

Eve's answer above is correct.

I'd just like to point out that had you written your code in a more readable way, you could have solved this yourself very easily by stepping through the code.

```
var collectionToIterate = agentNewTraining.AllCoursesTaken.TakeWhile(c => c.Valid);
foreach (var course in collectionToIterate)
{
  //...
}
```

You would have seen right away that the collectionToIterate was not what you expected.  You were not "exiting the entire loop", you simply had no items to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` instead:

```
foreach (var course in agentNewTraining.AllCoursesTaken.Where(c => c.Valid))
```

Or check the condition using an `if` statement:

```
foreach (var course in agentNewTraining.AllCoursesTaken) {
  if (course.Valid) {
    ...
  }
}
```